# Getting error when creating a tunnel in django application

Tags: python, django, postgresql, ssh-tunnel

I have a django application in which I am trying to access my database using a tunnel connection. The tunnel needs the username and a private key file to connect. I am able to connect the tunnel using 'putty' app. But for creating the connection in django application I am using 'sshtunnel' package provided by django.

`
from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder

ssh_tunnel = SSHTunnelForwarder(('myhost.host', 22), ssh_private_key=os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'privateKey.ppk'), ssh_private_key_password='password@123', ssh_username='ssh-user', remote_bind_address=('localhost', 5432))
ssh_tunnel.start()
`

But got the error -
"sshtunnel.BaseSSHTunnelForwarderError: Could not establish session to SSH gateway"
Can someone help me find out, what I am doing wromg?